# remove subdomain from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, subdomain

I'm using a constraint to set a subdomain for pages in my app

```
get '/', to: 'referal#new', constraints: { subdomain: 'keystrategy' }
```

It brings me to `keystrategy.[mypage]`. This page only contains a few lines :

```
<%= form_for @referal, url: {action: "create", subdomain: false} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :referer %>
  <input type="hidden" value="keystrategy">
 <%= f.submit "Valider" %>
<% end %>
```

But when I try to load this page, I get the following error :

```
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"referal", :subdomain=>"keystrategy"}
```

What am I missing ? I thought the `subdomain: false` would prevent this

Comment: code looks good but you can try `url_for controller:"referal" action: "create", subdomain: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out it was not about the form itself, but rather because of routing. When using a subdomain, every new route generated by

```
resources :whatever
```

assumes you're doing so in your current subdomain. Therefore, if `subdomain.yousite.com` points to a view including a form, the form will be handled by `subdomain.yoursite.com/whatevers`, as a POST request.

So, you have to make sure that this route includes your subdomain. In your `routes.rb` file, add these lines:

```
get '/', to: 'whatever#new', constraints: { subdomain: 'yoursubdomain' }
post '/whatevers', to: 'whatever#create', constraints: { subdomain: 'yoursubdomain' }
```

Your form should look like this :

```
<%= form_for @referal do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :referer %>
    <input name="referal-type" type="hidden" value="keystrategy">
    <%= f.submit "Valider" %>
<% end %>
```

And you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
<%= form_for @referal, url: referal_url(subdomain: false) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :referer %>
  <input type="hidden" value="keystrategy">
  <%= f.submit "Valider" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried, get the following error : No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"referals", :subdomain=>"keystrategy"} missing required keys: [:id]